# How do I handle the SqlException "No Records Found" when using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql, exception, sqlexception

I'm using LINQ to SQL to call sprocs at my company.  Normally it works great but on some queries, if nothing is found it will throw a SqlException "No Records Found".

How should I handle this case?

Here is an example call I would make:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the pending messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="historySearchCriteria">The history search criteria.</param>
        /// <returns><c>List</c> of pending messages.</returns>
        public List<PendingMessage> GetPendingMessages(HistorySearchCriteria historySearchCriteria)
        {
            using (MessageDataContext db = new MessageDataContext(DatabaseProperties.MessageConnectionString))
            {
                List<PendingMessage> pendingMessages = new List<PendingMessage>();

                pendingMessages.AddRange(db.usp_search_message_pending(historySearchCriteria.AccountId,
                    historySearchCriteria.TrackingNumber,
                    historySearchCriteria.StartDateTime,
                    historySearchCriteria.EndDateTime)
                    .Select(p => new PendingMessage()
                    {
                        Account = p.account,
                        ActionType = (OrderActionType) Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderActionType), p.action_type.ToString()),
                        AttemptsRemaining = p.attempts_remaining,
                        Message = p.message
                    }));

                return pendingMessages;
            }           
        }
```

What is the best way to handle the fact that I simply want to return an empty list if no records are found.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply catch that Exception, and `return new List<PendingMessage>;` within the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx).

Somthing like:

```
pendingMessages.AddRange(
                db.usp_search_message_pending
                   (
                       historySearchCriteria.AccountId,
                       historySearchCriteria.TrackingNumber,
                       historySearchCriteria.StartDateTime,
                       historySearchCriteria.EndDateTime
                   )
          .DefaultIfEmpty()
          .Select( /* select clause here */)
);
```

Comment: I just tested it and it still throws the SqlException "No Records Found".

Comment: Try adding DefaultIfEmpty before AddRange and see what happens.

Comment: I could be wrong (frequently am!) but the question's wording lead me to think that the sproc is throwing the exception. If that's the case, the result will never be 'empty', but will be an exception. So without changing the sproc, that exception must be caught as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the text "No Records Found" come from?

Execute the stored procedure from Management Studio using the same parameters that result in the exception.

Does SSMS report an error?

If not, separate the C# line into 3 steps:

- Invoking the stored procedure
- Check for != null and invoke Select()
- Check for != null and call AddRange()